# What is the difference between serving a page as text/xml and application/xhtml+xml?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, html

What is the difference between serving a page as **text/xml** and **application/xhtml+xml** ?

Comment: Recommended reading on this topic: http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#application-xhtml-xml):

> The 'application/xhtml+xml' media type [RFC3236] is the primary media
>   type for XHTML Family documents. 'application/xhtml+xml' should be
>   used for serving XHTML documents to XHTML user agents (agents that
>   explicitly indicate they support this media type). This media type
>   must be used when writing documents using XHTML Family document types
>   that add elements and attributes from foreign namespaces, such as
>   XHTML+MathML [XHTML+MathML].

So use `application/xhtml+xml` to serve your XHTML pages if the client supports it, otherwise you could use `text/html`.

Another quote from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#media-types):

> 1. If the Accept header explicitly contains application/xhtml+xml (with
>      either no "q" parameter or a positive "q" value) deliver the document
>      using that media type.
> 2. If the Accept header explicitly contains
>      text/html (with either no "q" parameter or a positive "q" value)
>      deliver the document using that media type.
> 3. If the accept header
>      contains "* /*" (a convention some user agents use to indicate that
>      they will accept anything), deliver the document using text/html.
>
> In other words, requestors that advertise they support XHTML family
>   documents will receive the document in the XHTML media type, and all
>   other requestors that (at least claim to) support HTML or "everything"
>   will receive the document using the HTML media type. Dealing with user
>   agents that satisfy none of these criteria is outside the scope of
>   this document.
>
> When an XHTML document does NOT adhere to the guidelines, it should
>   only be delivered as media type application/xhtml+xml.

`text/xml` should not be used for serving XHTML web pages. You could use it to serve other XML documents that do not represent XHTML.

Comment: quick question: can we also write **application/xhtml+xml** as **application/xml+xhtml** ? in other words can we tilt the order any how we like?

Comment: @Pacerier, no, it wouldn't be standard.

Comment: fast question: what about **application / xhtml** or **[SPACE]application/xhtml+xml** or **application[SPACE]/xhtml+xml[SPACE]**

Comment: @Pacerier, hmm, good question. I can't be affirmative about this. Will have to check. What I can say is that I have never seen someone using it. But I am not sure whether it would pose some problems to user agents.

Comment: @Pacerier: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html - I can not find any type or subtype that contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the only difference is that text/xml documents' encoding should default to US-ASCII (if there's no encoding specified in the HTTP header or source), but in application/xml and */*+xml, UTF-8 is the default encoding. I think no browser adheres to this.

The application/xhtml+xml MIME type *should* be primarily used for XHTML (and for SVG, you should use image/svg+xml). However, in practice, there is no difference between these MIME types because browsers use the same XML parser for all XML-related MIME types.

Remember that application/xhtml+xml doesn't say anything about the content of the document. You're still required to specify `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute for elements which belong to the XHTML namespace. Otherwise they will be treated as generic XML elements.